# Laravel 5.8 Fresh Deployment Not Working In Hostinger Shared Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, deployment, web-hosting

I tried to deploy a fresh laravel application. I installed a laravel 5.8 and upload to github repository.

The repository or project folder is working since I tried to run `php artisan serve` and it successfully shows the laravel home screen page.

I tried to connect in my shared hosting using ssh.

Here's the steps that I've done:

1. Access thru ssh
2. create a project folder `mkdir my-assignment-calculator` then cd my-assignment-calculator
3. Clone project repository. `git clone **repo_url**`
4. Navigate the project folder, `cd my-assignment-calculator`
5. Copy .env file, `cp .env-example .env`
6. Install composer packages. `composer install`
7. Then copy all files in `Public` folder to public_html folder
8. Go to public_html then update index.php, `nano index.php`
9. In index.php, I update these two lines, the vendor/autoload.php and the bootstrap/app.php

Here's the sample code for #9:

```
require __DIR__.'/../my-assignment-calculator/my-assignment-calculator/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once 
__DIR__.'/../my-assignment-calculator/my-assignment-calculator/bootstrap/app.php';
```

#### Here's the structure of my project folder

```
-public_html
-domains
    --my_assignment_calculator
    --my_assignment_calculator
        ---laravel files
```

The current output is only white screen. I tried to check the developers tools or devtools, there's no error. It's just a white background. It's the same as before.

I tried to check .htaccess file and I didn't touch this file. Here is the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

#### So what is the expected output

Should display laravel welcome or home screen page

Comment: try replacing "__DIR__." with the full path, i've noticed the "__DIR__." does not work on some servers.

Answer (score 0):

laravel folder is in root then all your public folder files transfer it into public_html then go to your index file in your public_html configure by adding laravel directory like this:

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```